# Retrieving data from secondary table into a primary table via APEX form submission

Tags: oracle-apex

I appreciate any help you can provide.

I am using **Apex 4.2** and I have a form on a table (`FC_PRIMARY`) with the following columns (below). When the user enters data for the fields with an `*`, I want to return data from another table (`FC_JOB`) and have it populate in the primary table once they hit the "Insert" button.  Any ideas of how I can utilize the form item options or processes to obtain this result using a SQL query?

For example,

When a user enters data into the `JOB__ROLE*` field, I want to create a processes than upon submission of the form, `APEX` pulls data from the `FC_JOB` table based on that `JOB__ROLE*` field and matches that Job role from `FC_JOB` table.  The value that gets pulled over would go into the `FC_PRIMARY TABLE>>C3 COLUMN`

```
FC_JOB table

ID  JOB__CODE1  JOB_DESCRIPTION1
1   IT            IT
2   HR             Human Resources



ID
REGION*
COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION*
BUSINESS_LINE*
CUSTOMER_NAME*
JOB__ROLE*
CURRENCY*
EMPLOYEE_STATUS*
COMMENTS*
C1
ENTITY
**C3****
ACCOUNT
JAN*
FEB*
MAR*
APR*
MAY*
JUN*
JUL*
AUG*
SEP*
OCT*
NOV*
DEC*
```

Comment: Basically, is the "Job" field supposed to behave like a select list or popup list of values, where you can select a job based on the code and description but return an id into the primary table? (And thus indicating that the primary table has a foreign key to the job table). Or do you actually want to put the code and description into columns in the primary table? As for all the other fields you indicated with `*`: are these pulled from somewhere too?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

1. Change JOB_ROLE item type to a select list. For list of values query, you can use `select JOB__DESCRIPTION1, JOB__CODE1 from FC_JOB`
2. If it doesn't already exist, create a new hidden item called C3. For Source type, select **database column**, and enter the relevant column name.
3. Create a new pl/sql process after submit. Ensure it takes place before any automatic row processing. Write a simple statement that selects relevant data from FC_JOB and stores it in the hidden item C3, using item JOB__ROLE in the where clause.